# NSFileManager Thread Safe

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsfilemanager

According to Apple's docs the NSFileManager is thread safe when doing basic file operations:

"The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations."

How can I generally perform all my file operations on a background thread while still being sure that all file operations get performed in the same order as they are called by the main thread?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to look in to NSOperationQueue or GCD. Here a link to some Apple Docs.: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: My 5 minutes are up and I can't edit my comment but, I meant to also say that I think you should implement a serial queue.

Comment: Yeah, I know about GCD but wasn't sure what exactly to search for. I will have a look... So do you think a global serial queue does make sense in my case?

Comment: Definitely. You said that you need to perform basic operations on a background thread in a certain order, which is what is serial queue is used for. I personally like NSOperationQueue because it's a high-level API but, ultimately it's up to you. If you do choose to use NSOperationQueue be sure to set maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1. You can also add dependencies for each operation such as, Operation B depends on the completion of Operation A using the addDependency: method.

Comment: @Max While I prefer operation queues for many tasks (network queues, image processing queues, etc.), for basic synchronization via a serial queue, I'd generally advise GCD. It's easy and efficient and very well suited for synchronizing interaction with a specific object across threads. In the [Eliminating Lock-Based Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) section of the _Concurrency Programming Guide_, they illustrate it using GCD for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code to make sure file operations are done in the order you want. I have also written a sample function which can be called from any thread to do file operations too.

```
    //this will create a queue 
    dispatch_queue_t _serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.name", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    //call methods on different threads, to be performed one after the other.
    dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf("1"); //call 1st method here 
     });
    printf("2");
    dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf("3"); //call second method here 
    });
    printf("4");
```

The execution order will be 1234

Below is an example of thread safe NSFileManager method you can call.

```
-(void)threadSafeMethod{ //you can call this method from any thread and do file operations

NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sourceFile]) {

  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourceFile
                            toPath:destFile
                             error:&error]) {
    // Deal with error
  }
}

}
```

If you take a look at the Class documentation for NSFileManager the overview section contains this warning:

> The methods of the shared FileManager object can be called from
>   multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive
>   notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link
>   operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager
>   object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager
>   to initiate your operations.

Anyway the difference is only how you initiate the NSFileManager, one with defaultManager and the other allocating an instant of NSFileManager.

Hope this helps.